# How to prove that a certain block matrix is positive semi definite, which depends on a undetermined submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

How should I proof the following matrix $$M = \begin{pmatrix}
Z-A^TZA & -A^TZB\\
-B^TZA & -B^TZB
\end{pmatrix},$$ to be positive semidefinite? The matrices $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $ B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $ are known. The matrix $Z\in R^{n\times n}$ is unknown and the actual goal is to construct the matrix $Z$ such that $M$ is positive semi-definite.

I have tried the following things:

- constructing $Z$ as a diagonal matrix and by using a symbolic programming library (sympy) I found the expressions for the eigenvalues of $M$. Here I found out that for this specific $Z$, the eigenvalues will be indefinite (larger or smaller than zero)
- using theories off *Schur Complement*: [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness). For example, in order for the third option of the link to be true; $Z-A^TZA \succ 0$ and $ -B^TZB-(-B^TZA)^T(Z-A^TZA)^{-1}(-A^TZB) \succeq 0$, $(-B^TZA)^T= -A^TZB$ -> $Z$ should be symmetric.

I think I could write this all out to be a larger Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) and try to solve using python for example. However, I'm not sure if that is true and if this is the correct approach as this would take some time to implement this in a python code.

Do you have any suggestions or feedback for a different approach?

(My mathematical knowledge is not so great as I come from a mechanical/control engineering background. Furthermore, this is my first question on a stack website. I apologize for any trivial mistakes I made)

EDIT:

Extra info regarding the matrices $A$,$B$; they are so-called state-space matrices which are part of a Linear Time-Invariant(LTI) dynamical model [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation). The standard form is $x_{k+1}=Ax_k + Bu$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ represents the *state* of the system and $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the input to this dynamical model. The matrix $A$ is the mapping of the current state of the system to the next state (in time) and $B$ represents the mapping of the input to the next state (in time).
These state-space matrices ($A, B$) are thus known as they represent the dynamics of a system. However, they have no special mathematical properties.

Comment: What do you know about A and B besides their size? Are they positive definite and/or symmetric? That would be kind of nice to know.

Comment: I would like to clarify the question.
Do I understand correctly that given matrices $A$ and $B$, we need to construct matrix $Z$ so that matrix M is positive semi-definite.

Comment: @JordiManyerFuertes thank you for your quick reply. I have added extra info in my edit; basically, there are no extra mathematical properties (I think) which I can share.

Comment: @kabenyuk thank you for your quick reply. You're indeed correct! I can see that you edited my question; should I change something else or approve your edit?

Answer (score 2):

This will not be a definite answer, but I think it can help:

Let's assume $Z$ is symmetric, and consider a general vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ decomposed as $v^T = (v_1^T , v_2^T)$ suitably to match matrix block dimensions.

Now for $M$ to be spd, we need $v^T M v \geq 0 \ \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.
If we develop the expression, we get

$\begin{equation} 0 \leq v_1^T Z v_1 - v_1^T A^T Z A v_1 - v_1^T A^T Z B v_2 - v_2^T B^T Z A v_1 - v_2^T B^T Z B v_2 \end{equation}$

and taking advantage that $Z$ is symmetric and regrouping terms we have that

$0 \leq v_1^T Z v_1 - \left(v_1 A + v_2 B\right)^T Z \left(v_1 A + v_2 B \right)$

or even

$0 \leq \left(v_1 + v_1 A - v_2 B\right)^T Z \left(v_1 - v_1 A - v_2 B \right)$

which is quite more manageable.

Cheers!

Comment: This is an interesting contribution. Actually I started from your developed expression and put the terms into this matrix M with the idea to proof this inequality. However, I do like your last step. Maybe this will help

Comment: I believe it is now solved after my edit. I was a little asleep this morning and didn't see the easy follow-up XD

Comment: Thank you for your extra step. However, I'm not sure If I agree: 
regarding your first "regrouping terms" the sequence should be flipped: 

$0 \leq v_1^T Z v_1 - \left(A v_1  + B v_2 \right)^T Z \left(A v_1 + B v_2  \right)$.

However, this is not my main concern. If I would work out your last expression, $0 \leq \left(v_1 - v_1 A - v_2 B\right)^T Z \left(v_1 - v_1 A - v_2 B \right)$,  I have a lot of extra cross terms which were not present in the original equation 
$0 \leq v_1^T Z v_1 - v_1^T A^T Z A v_1 - v_1^T A^T Z B v_2 - v_2^T B^T Z A v_1 - v_2^T B^T Z B v_2 $

Comment: Working out your suggested equation, $0 \leq \left(v_1 - Av_1  - Bv_2 \right)^T Z \left(v_1 - Av_1 - B v_2  \right)$, where I flipped the sequence, gives me:

$ 0 \leq v_1^T Z v_1  - v_1^TZAv_1-v_1^TZBv_2-v_1^TA^Zv_1+ v_1^T A^T Z A v_1 - v_1^T A^T Z B v_2 -v_2^TB^TZv_1+ v_2^T B^T Z A v_1 + v_2^T B^T Z B v_2 $.

So there are four extra terms and some minus/plusses are different. Did I make I mistake?

Comment: I think regrouping the terms and assuming $Z$ to be symmetric gives: 
 $(v_1-Av_1-Bv_2)^TZ(v_1+Av_1+Bv_2)$. This ensures the extra cross-terms from my other comment are eliminated. However, this new equation cannot be written to: 
$u^TZu$ like you suggested.

Comment: You are 100% right. I've edited my post accordingly. Then I must say I do not see an easy way to continue this... I will try to think about it if I have time.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my new comments at least! :)